# Update hyperlink to a file when the file is moved to another folder

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have files in two folders that are manually moved between each other. The Excel file has a list of all the file names, in these two folders, in column C.

The code creates a hyperlink for these file names in that list. I am able to run the code with just one folder link. In case, the file is moved to the other folder, the hyperlink will no longer work.

How do I add another file path in the code and how should I update it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown))
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add cell, "Y:\training\" & cell.Value & ".xlsm"
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Hyperlinks to Files

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Const Extension As String = ".xlsm"
    Dim FolderPaths As Variant
    FolderPaths = Array( _
        "Y:\Training\", _
        "Y:\Sleeping\")
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FolderPath As Variant
    Dim FilePath As String

    For Each cell In Range(Range("C3"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            For Each FolderPath In FolderPaths
                FilePath = FolderPath & cell.Value & Extension
                If Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then
                    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add cell, FilePath
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next FolderPath
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!!!!..............It works like a charm!